# Binding Applescript to a mouse button

Tags: applescript

I wrote some Apple script to take advantage of the extra buttons of my mouse (say invoke 'Back' from my web browser) and it runs fine inside AppleScript editor. Now I'd like to bind it to my mouse's 'Button 4'. Saving the script as 'script' or 'bundle' would only cause the button-click to open the editor instead of executing it. Saving it as 'Application' will do the work but it involves opening the application, doing its job, and exiting the application, so each time there's a flash. Any way to get rid of this flash? One way is to run the script in the background but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Butler](http://manytricks.com/butler/) for this kind of thing. You can assign a keystroke to your mouse button, then tell Butler to run your script on that keystroke.

I can't help but wonder if there's not built in support for that already with your mouse's software, though. I can't remember the last mouse I had that the 'Back' option wasn't built-in.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use a program that can run a script with keyboard shortcuts. [Here's a free one](http://www.shadowlab.org/softwares/spark.php). Then instead of running the script from a mouse button, you just assign the mouse button to perform the keyboard shortcut.